# Datatype issue in sha256 encryption in python

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, sha256

I am making a database project in which I am using python and MySQL. What happens is I encrypt the user password and store it in the sql database as varchar datatype.

But when I call it back from the database, it comes as a string and shows the following error:

[image: Error]

This is the function:

```
    def decrypt(password, hashed):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, hashed)
```

In this, the 'hashed' variable is called from databse using sql and returns as a string

What should I do?

EDIT:
Encryption Code:

```
    def encrypt(password):
        password=str(password)
        return pwd_context.hash(password)
```

Comment: Your password is meant to contain the digest like [docs](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#welcome). hence "Missing Digest Error". If you think that's not right, show the value and the encryption code. (technically hashes aren't decrypted, only verified).

Comment: @danblack 
I checked it again and the 'hashed' variable contains the digest. that's why I am not getting why the "Missing Digest Error"

Comment: Please add the error message as text instead of an image, this makes it easier to find and read.